Creating a loop by specific column vba
I am looking to clean up the below code. I have 2 codes that I am looking to run depending on what is in the column, and I am running this on 30+ columns of data. I'm looking for a way to minimize what is happening so it's easier to add or subtract columns as needed. Not sure what the best practice would be but I was thinking something along the lines of making a list of needed columns, then declaring i as the first column, looping through the list of needed columns with next i and then stopping once it's done. Ideally then I can easily add and subtract columns as needed.
Sub YouGoGlenCoCo()
'
' YouGoGlenCoCo Macro
' 
'

Dim rngTmp      As Range
Dim rngCell     As Range
Dim mystring    As String
Dim apt         As Worksheet


Sheets("ALL TYPES").Select
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTmp = Intersect(.Range("V:V"), .UsedRange)
    End With
    TheManInGauze rngTmp

Sheets("ALL TYPES").Select
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTmp = Intersect(.Range("X:X"), .UsedRange)
    End With
    ReturnTheSlab rngTmp
    TheManInGauze rngTmp

'// this code repeats 32 different times for different columns


'// Reset
    Set rngTmp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Update Complete, please verify"

End Sub



Sub ReturnTheSlab(rngTmp As Range)


    For Each rngCell In rngTmp
        rngCell.Replace what:="#", replacement:="" '// this is to remove #to prevent errors
        rngCell.Replace what:="$", replacement:="This is a dollar sign"
        rngCell.Replace what:="%", replacement:="This is a percent sign"
        If InStr(1, rngCell.Value, "$") > 0 Then
            rngCell.Value = rngCell.Value & " This is a dollar sign after"
        End If

          
    Next rngCell

'
End Sub



Sub TheManInGauze(rngTmp As Range)
    For Each rngCell In rngTmp
        If InStr(1, rngCell.Offset(0, 1), "$") > 0 Then
            rngCell.Value = "Adding words " & rngCell.Value
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Sub

I have tried using Arrays to call the columns instead but I am always given errors but i'm not sure if i'm too green to appropriately understand Arrays or if it's an issue with other parts of my code.
I have also tried to make a loop declaring i as a column but was unsuccessful.

"I am always given errors" which line(s), which error?

I feel there is a lot missing from your post... what is the end goal?  You mention "this code repeats 32 different times for different columns," but without knowing the end goal on each column, there may be different requirements.  Initially I am thinking Select Case to determine your range, etc., but that would require a lot more information to flesh out.

Sorry for not providing more information! I'm just looking to declutter my code. The 5 - 6 lines declaring rngTmp and calling out to the different formulas is basically copy/pasted 30+ times for each column I need cleaned up. I was hopeful there was a way I could make a list list that that could be referenced and then I could just add or subtract columns as needed. Something like: I need columns AA,AC,AZ,BD,BQ,etc then I could delcare i as a column, use next i to run down the needed columns then stop after that.

Applying Changes to Specific Columns of a Range

Not tested (it compiled)!

Main
Sub YouGoGlenCoCo()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "ALL TYPES"
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 1
    ' The following three arrays need to be 'in sync'.
    Dim COLUMN_STRINGS() As Variant: COLUMN_STRINGS = VBA.Array( _
        "V", "X")
    Dim APPLY_ReturnTheSlab() As Variant: APPLY_ReturnTheSlab = VBA.Array( _
        0, 1)
    Dim APPLY_TheManInGauze() As Variant: APPLY_TheManInGauze = VBA.Array( _
        1, 1)
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, use 'ActiveWorkbook' instead.
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Reference the whole range, from column 'A' to the last column,
    ' and from the specified first row to the last row of the used range.
    
    Dim rg As Range, lcell As Range, RowsCount As Long
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set lcell = .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)
        RowsCount = lcell.Row - FIRST_ROW + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Range(FIRST_ROW, "A"), lcell)
    End With
            
    ' Process each column using the helper methods.
    ' The 'cData' array is passed by reference i.e. it is possibly modified
    ' in the 'APPLY...' methods. Also, 'WasFound' is passed by reference
    ' 'signaling' if any modification in the 'cData' array occurred.
            
    Dim crg As Range, cData() As Variant, c As Long, WasFound As Boolean
            
    For c = 0 To UBound(COLUMN_STRINGS)
        WasFound = False
        Set crg = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
            Set crg = rg.Columns(COLUMN_STRINGS(c))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not crg Is Nothing Then
            GetSingleColumnRangeByRef cData, crg, RowsCount
            If APPLY_ReturnTheSlab(c) = 1 Then
                ReturnTheSlab cData, crg, RowsCount, WasFound
            End If
            If APPLY_TheManInGauze(c) = 1 Then
                TheManInGauze cData, crg, RowsCount, COLUMN_OFFSET, WasFound
            End If
            If WasFound Then crg.Value = cData
        End If
    Next c
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Update complete, please verify.", vbInformation

End Sub

Help
Sub ReturnTheSlab( _
        ByRef cData As Variant, _
        ByVal crg As Range, _
        ByVal RowsCount As Long, _
        ByRef WasFound As Boolean)
    
    Const SEARCH_STRING As String = "$"
    Const SUFFIX As String = " This is a dollar sign after"
    
    ' Not sure about 'xlPart' or 'xlWhole'!
    ' You must add these arguments, there is no default!!!
    ' There is no default for 'MatchCase' either. 'True' should be faster.
    crg.Replace "#", "", xlPart, , True ' prevent errors
    crg.Replace "$", "This is a dollar sign", xlWhole, , True
    crg.Replace "%", "This is a percent sign", xlWhole, , True
    
    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        Value = cData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            If InStr(Value, SEARCH_STRING) > 0 Then
                cData(r, 1) = Value & SUFFIX
                WasFound = True
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
End Sub

Sub TheManInGauze( _
        ByRef cData() As Variant, _
        ByVal crg As Range, _
        ByVal RowsCount As Long, _
        ByVal ColumnOffset As Long, _
        ByRef WasFound As Boolean)
    
    Const SEARCH_STRING As String = "$"
    Const PREFIX As String = "Adding words "
    
    Dim org As Range: Set org = crg.Offset(, ColumnOffset)
    Dim oData() As Variant: GetSingleColumnRangeByRef oData, org, RowsCount
    
    Dim cValue As Variant, oValue As Variant, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        oValue = oData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(oValue) Then
            If InStr(oValue, SEARCH_STRING) > 0 Then
                cValue = cData(r, 1)
                If Not IsError(cValue) Then
                    If Len(cValue) > 0 Then
                        cData(r, 1) = PREFIX & cValue
                        WasFound = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r

End Sub

Sub GetSingleColumnRangeByRef( _
        ByRef Data() As Variant, _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal RowsCount As Long)
    If RowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
End Sub


Ignoring for the moment that you seem to be calling different sets of methods on different columns, a loop might look something like this:
Sub YouGoGlenCoCo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arrCols, el
    
    arrCols = Split("V,X,AA,AB,AC", ",") 'add required columns here
    
    For Each el In arrCols
        Set rngTmp = Application.Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(el))
        TheManInGauze rngTemp
    Next el
    
End Sub

